# how to grab an input in an html file and grab it from javascript file to

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following set up in html

```
<input maxlength="1" type="number" min="1" max="4" id ="c0r0"></input>
```

this has a text box where I can select a number 1 to 4
if I select a number I want it in my js file as a variable

I have tried this in my js file:

```
var tt = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
console.log(tt);
```

I need it tt var be equal to the input. Do I need to add a button to submit my input? or once I select 1 through 4 my js file can grab the value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: no it does not I did use that same question to try and see if that would work but when the input is 1 through 4 and not empty tt does not equal the input set

Comment: Not sure what is you actual use case. But have answered this with a snippet, check that. Also it will be easy if you can post an example of your code replicating the problem you are facing. That will help you  get the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the two simples ways of doing this.

#### Method 1:

Attach a change event listener to the input element i.e. a function that's called every time the value changes. Then use the target property of the event to get the value. For more details read this [onchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange)

#### Method 2

Get the html element reference using the `getElementById` ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)) and then use the that element to access the value.

Note: Using `getElementById` is easy and simple as you get the target element while other methods return a collection and you will have to find the element of concern in the collection.

Below is a small demo of the above recommended methods

```js
function getValue(event) {
  // Method 1
  var val = event.target.value
  console.log('first box:' + val);
}

function method2() {
  // Method 2
  val = document.getElementById('c1r1').value;
  console.log('second box:' + val)
}
```

```html
<input maxlength="1" type="number" min="1" max="4" id="c0r0" onchange="getValue(event)" />

<input maxlength="1" type="number" min="1" max="4" id="c1r1" onchange="method2(event)" />
```

Comment: thanks! I used the second method b/c I like that it grabs from Id

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out these two things

1. `<input type="number">` elements are not really made for "selecting" values. Although you can of course use some autocomplete library to help you with that. A `<select>` element is probably the more natural choice for the task.
2. The variable you desire can be easily set up. In fact I would suggest to create a `const` instead:

```
const tt=document.querySelector("input");

// the "variable" you require is then tt.value:

console.log(tt.value)
```

In a "real" application you should probably use a more specific CSS selector, like a class or an identity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and Change :

```html
<input maxlength="1" type="number" min="1" max="4" id ="c0r0"></input>
```

To :

```
<input maxlength="1" type="number" min="1" max="4" id="c0r0" />
```